# Choosing method/parameter names in Java

Tags: java, naming-conventions

How should I choose which method names and parameter names/types to use in Java (or any other language for that matter)? And why are there so many ways to choose?

If many people work on a project, it's annoying to see different ways of naming in different parts of the code, especially if people are inconsistent about their usage. Why didn't the inventors of the language simply state a standard -- "This is the EXACT way methods and parameters should be named. Period."?

It would be easier to do programming then. I get stressed by having to choose between a gazillion different parameter/method names each time I write a method and trying to be consequent about how I choose throuhgout the code.

---

Example 1:

```
public void handleFile(String file)
public void handleFile(String fileName)
public void handleFile(File file)
```

---

Example 2:

```
public void exec(String command)
public void exec(String cmd)
public void exec(String commandString)
public void exec(String cmdString)
public void execute(String command)
public void execute(Command command)
public void execute(Command cmdObj)
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Actually what is so stressful regarding parameters???

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with a group of people, it might be worth your while to establish a coding standard.  Google this phrase and you'll find examples.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, naming conventions exist for the Java language: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Arguments, like variable, should be written in camelCase, should generally not be abbreviated except for well-known acronyms (URL, HTTP, etc.), and, most important, should describe the role of the argument and not its type. Its type is knwon: it's written just before the argument.

So prefer

```
void copy(SomeClass source, SomeClass destination)
```

to

```
void copy(SomeClass someClass1, SomeClass someClass2)
```

Regarding your examples, here are the ones I would accept:

```
public void handleFile(String fileName)
public void handleFile(File file)
```

Both are acceptable, because the first one handles a name and the second one handles a file.

```
public void execute(String command)
public void execute(Command command)
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter names are a hint to the developer using it as to what should be passed.  They should be as clear as possible without being needlessly verbose.

I suggest you do what you think is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is - it doesn't matter. The method name is more important, the argument names should simply describe the argument. Trying to enforce rules about names will be hard - you can't formulate sufficient rules for that.

The argument type on the other hand is important - you should choose the most specific argument type. If you need simply a filename, then pass a String. If yon need to know whether you can read a file, pass `File`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the first choice is the name of the parameter Class in [camelcase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase):

```
void someMethod(SomeClass someClass)
```

Except when a String/primitive or boxed, where you give meaning to it and usually drop the type:

```
void someMethod(String filename) // note filename is so common, it's rarely "fileName"
```

But sometimes it is just "a string" - here are some common choices

```
void trim(String aString)
void trim(String string)
void trim(String s)
```

Whatever the style, your team should agree to a naming convention and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well traditionally people were constrained to the amount of chars they could fit on a screen so short variables names were preferred.

Now days with big screen, automatic line wrapping and autocompletion you can name things as long as you want.

It all depends on how you team decides is the best way and you should enforce a coding standard that you all agree on.

Personally I try to name variables to accurately describe what they are holding therefore is it holds a `TableViewController` I will call it `tableViewController` that way it is clear when I look at the code again in a day, weeks... time that I am using a `TableViewController` without having to double check. If I calle the variable `tvc` the or other of shortenings you can think of it may not be as clear what the intent of my code is.